# Specific action on entities (ban, unban, make current, change status) in my RESTful API design?

Tags: rest

In my current API design I'm following these rules:

- `PATCH` is used to partially update a resource
- `POST` is used to create resources
- `PUT` isn't used at all

I need to **expose specific update actions** (not exposed as `PATCH`, for security reasons), i.e. change the status of an order to "confirmed", "partially confirmed" or "refused".

I'm struggling on:

- `POST /carts/:id/:status` and `DELETE /carts/:id/:status`: seems wrong as `POST` should create resources
- `PATCH /carts/:id/:status`: seems wrong because the payload would be empty

Which one would be the most consistent and appropriate with the above API design? Do I have other options?

Comment: Why not `PUT`? `PUT /carts/:id/status` with a body of `confirmed` would make a lot of sense…

Comment: @deceze that sounds interesting, need to search about the semantic of PUT

Answer (score 0):

It may help to review [Webber 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m08s)

> You have to learn to use HTTP to trigger business activity as a side effect of moving documents around the network.

---

> I need to expose specific update actions (not exposed as PATCH, for security reasons), i.e. change the status of an order to "confirmed", "partially confirmed" or "refused".

How would you do this on the Web?

The most common answer would look something like this: you would have a web page for "the order"; and that page would include hyperlinks to some forms - it might be a simple "change order status form", or you might have different forms for each change.  When we submit the form, the browser would create from form data and metadata an HTTP POST request, targeting whatever resource was specified by the form.

Important takeaways

- [It is okay to use POST](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post).
- The server can choose whatever URI it likes as the form target.

One convenient choice would be to use the URI for "the order" web page, because that allows you to take advantage of the general purpose [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9111.html#name-invalidating-stored-respons) defined by the HTTP standard.

---

You can, of course, use PUT or PATCH semantics instead, if you like.  The primary difference is that these methods use remote authoring semantics - they are the HTTP methods we would use if we were trying to edit a web page.

To change the status of an order, it might go roughly like this: you would GET the current web page, and edit your local copy to change the status information.  Then you would use HTTP to save your copy of the web page on the server:

- For PUT, the payload of the request would be the entire web page with your edits.
- For PATCH, the payload of the request would be a patch document describing just your edits.

The server would then need to either accept your request (applying your changes to its copy of the web page) or reject them (for example, if those changes are not consistent with business policy).

---

> Which one would be the most consistent and appropriate with the above API design? Do I have other options?

You'll probably have an easier time if you [relax the restriction](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post) that POST is only used to create resources.

Remember, the world wide web is the reference implementation of the REST architectural style, and it was catastrophically successful.  Yet PUT and PATCH were used only rarely -- almost all information was carried to web servers using POST semantics.

But if must limit yourself to these rules for non technical reasons, then you might consider a resource model where information is sent to the business by creating new resources on the web server.  In other words, instead of changing the status of the order by editing the order web page, you could instead create a new "change the status of the order" document on the server.

(Technically, you could use any of POST/PUT/PATCH to create the new document, but POST is normal and consistent with your constraints, so it seems a reasonable starting point).